# MongoDB: Create Mongoose Model / Schema from document stored in MongoDB

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, model, mongoose

As the title describes, I am trying to find out if I can instantiate a new mongoose model and schema with the JSON of a existing MongoDB document? It seems like I could do it as long as I have retrieve the document before Mongoose runs.

Is this possible? Ideally I would like to do it on the fly where I do NOT need to restart node.

**** Edit ****** Here is what I have tried.
note: the setTimeout is in there incase the schema creation is async. This is a down and dirty mockup just to see if this concept works. :).
THIS Does NOT Work!!!

```
function initModels(models) {

    for (var i = 0, l = models.length; i < l; i++) {
        console.log(models[i])
        exports[models[i].name + "Schema"] = mongoose.Schema(models[i].model, {collection: "ModelData"});

        (function(itrModel){
            var model = itrModel;
            setTimeout(function(){
                exports[model.name] = mongoose.model(model.name.toUpperCase(), model.name + "Schema");
            },2000)
        })(models[i])
    }
}

exports.getModels = function () {
    DataConnection.Connect(function (db) {

        var collectionName = "Models";
        var collection = db.collection(collectionName);

        collection.find().toArray(function (err, models) {

            initModels(models);

        })
    })
};
```

Here is the model that is stored in the db

```
{
    "name" : {
        "type" : "String",
        "required" : true
    },
    "email" : {
        "type" : "String",
        "required" : false,
        "index" : true,
        "index" : true
    },
    "password" : {
        "type" : "String",
        "required" : true
    },
    "role" : {
        "type" : "String",
        "required" : true
    },
    "createDate" : {
        "type" : "Number",
        "required" : true
    }
}
```

Comment: The constructor of the Schema object just takes an object as a parameter. You'd meerly need to loop through the keys, sub keys and arrays within the document and add the key and data type for each path to an object, then pass that final object into the constructor. The only trick is how to determine the data type of each path. You'd have to test each value in the doc to determine if it's a string, number, date...

Comment: if `restart` is the only issue, why don't you try http://nodemon.io/